# Can searchResponse.getHits().getHits(); throw nullpointer exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We are getting a nullpointerexception at searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
I'm totally new to elastic search and don't know how it works but need to analyse this issue.

Let me know if it throws nullpointerexception in any case ? 
If it throws how to handle this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: would you post your code (or a sample that could reproduce the issue)?

Comment: *and don't know how it works* I would suggest reading their documentation, the do a great job at keeping it up to date

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of `InternalSearchResponse`, it looks like `hits` gets initialised with `SearchHits.empty()` even if the response is empty.

For the other cases, it always gets initialised with `new`. You can have a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchResponse.java).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception after an update from 7.4 to 7.17.

It seems that the hits variable of the internalResponse can be NULL, at least in 7.17.1 - could be related to HL request option *ignoreUnavailable* set to FALSE, and/or queering a no longer existing index.

searchResponse.getHits() can return NULL!